# Why isn't `RouterView` rendering any components?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

All components/screens render correctly if I insert them in the HTML manually, and the URL changes with no errors, but no content is shown in `<RouterView>`. Thank you.

main.ts

```js
import { createApp, VueElement } from 'vue';
import {router} from './data/router';
import AppWidget from './widgets/app.vue';
import * as types from './data/types';

globalThis.__VUE_OPTIONS_API__ = (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") as unknown as string;
globalThis.__VUE_PROD_DEVTOOLS__ = (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") as unknown as string;

const app = createApp(AppWidget);
app.use(router);
const root = app.mount(`.app`);
```

router.ts

```js
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router';
import * as constants from './settings';
import Home from '../widgets/home.vue';
import JournalScreen from '../widgets/journal/journalScreen.vue';

export const router = createRouter(
{
    history: createWebHistory(),
    routes:
    [
        { path: '/',                                    name: 'home',                               component: Home },
        { path: '/journal',                             name: 'journal',                            component: JournalScreen }
    ]
});
```

app.vue

```js
<!-- JS ----------------------------------------------------->
<script setup lang="ts">
import { RouterLink, RouterView, useRouter } from 'vue-router';
import {router} from '../data/router';
import JournalScreen from './journal/journalScreen.vue';

router.push('/journal');

</script>

<!-- HTML ----------------------------------------------------->
<template>  
    <RouterView >       
    </RouterView>
</template>
```

journal.vue

```js
<!-- JS ----------------------------------------------------->
<script setup lang="ts">
import { RouterLink, RouterView } from 'vue-router';
import * as types from '../../data/types';
import * as helper from '../../logic/helper';
import {state} from '../../data/state';
import JournalEntry from './journalEntry.vue';
import SignIn from '../io/dropboxSignin.vue';
import SaveToCloud from '../io/save.vue';

function mounted() {console.log('here');} //does not fire
</script>

<!-- HTML ----------------------------------------------------->
<template>
    <sign-in></sign-in> 
    <div>
        Entries
    </div>
    <div v-for="item in state.entries">
        <journal-entry :entry="item" :key="item.id"></journal-entry>
        <br />
    </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I didn't post all my commented code in the question because I thought it was irrelevant, but it turns out that if you have a commented line inside `RouterView` it doesn't render anything.

Once I changed

```html
<RouterView>
    <!-- <RouterLink to="/hi">Go to Hi page</RouterLink> -->
</RouterView>
```

to

```html
<RouterView>
</RouterView>
```

everything worked. I've logged a bug on the Vue site for this.

Answer (score -1):

`app.use(router);` makes your entire app aware of Vue Router, so you don't need to do anything like `import {router} from './data/router';` within any of your components.

Vue Router with Composition API has a different syntax than maybe what you're used to if you used it previously with Vue 2/Options API

It'd be best to thoroughly review the Vue Router [Composition API documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/composition-api.html) which goes over its usage.  The docs use Composition API with `setup()` function but the syntax is the same for `<script setup>`

In your case, this code in **app.vue**:

```
import {router} from './data/router';

router.push('/journal');
```

Should be replaced with:

```js
import { useRouter } from 'vue-router'

const router = useRouter()
router.push('/journal');
```

There is also one other issue with using mounted instead of [onMounted](https://vuejs.org/api/composition-api-lifecycle.html#onmounted) (which also needs to be imported)

**journal.vue**

```js
<script setup>
import { onMounted } from 'vue'

onMounted(() => {
  console.log('here');
})
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't help. And either way you import the router it'll be the same object I think.